# Converting a Date Number String to Word of day PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a PHP script outputting dates like this `2014-08-06` and i wish to make them output as `Wednesday 6th August 2014` instead.

I am already using the number previously so i need to take this from the variable of which holds the number string and convert that.

**The PHP**

```
function dateRange($start, $end) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    $diff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);

    $daysBetween = floor($diff/(60*60*24));

    $formattedDates = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $daysBetween; $i++) {
        $tmpDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start . " + $i days"));
        $formattedDates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tmpDate));
    }    
    return $formattedDates;
}


$start=$date_system_installed;
$end=$today;

$formattedDates = dateRange($start, $end);

    foreach ($formattedDates as $dt)
{
 echo $dt; //this is where i wish to change the number to the word/s. 
}
```

Comment: change this line `echo $dt;` to `echo date('l jS \of F Y',$dt);`

Comment: i get `Thursday 1st of January 1970 ` on all rows with that? @user2092317

Comment: date() is the way to go.. see the doc for all the format characters you can use. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` and `DateTime::format` to create a `DateTime` object and then create a string in the format you want:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dt)->format('l jS F Y');
```

Ideally what I would do is work with `DateTime` object all the way through:

```
function dateRange($start, $end) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $daysBetween = $start->diff($end)->format('%R%a');
    $formattedDates = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $daysBetween; $i++) {
        $formattedDates[] = clone $start->modify('+1 day');
    }    
    return $formattedDates;
}

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2014-08-01");
$end = new DateTime;
$formattedDates = dateRange($start, $end);
foreach ($formattedDates as $dt)
{
    echo $dt->format('l jS F Y');
}
```

See it working here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2003646deb0b39d501d7e49eb23edc3979a10762

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `date` http://php.net//manual/en/function.date.php

For example:

```
<?php

    $date = strtotime('2014-08-06');
    echo date('l jS F Y', $date);  //Wednesday 6th August 2014
    /*
        l - full name of week day, jS - day of month with suffix,
        F - full name of month, Y - year
    */
```

Comment: Now when i do this, it gives me words but all the words are wednesday. And the months are incorrect. The only thing consistent is the year?!

Comment: fix it. Sorry, it's my inattention.
Also if you not pass to date() second parameter, it will return you information about this day.